# How do the Hexblade warlock's Hex Warrior and Pact of the Blade features interact for two-handed weapons?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons, warlock

In the description of the [Hexblade warlock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#TheHexblade)'s Hex Warrior class feature (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 55), it states that you can bond with a weapon that lacks the two-handed property.

In the [Pact of the Blade](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#PactBoon) description, it states that you can make any weapon you want and that it can be used as your Hex Warrior weapon.

Can I use a two-handed weapon as my pact weapon?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Yes, you can use a two-handed weapon as your pact weapon, but...

We need to dissect things a little bit to understand what exactly that *means*.

The problem with Hex Warrior and Pact of the Blade is that people’s intuitive assumption of what’s going on *isn’t* actually what the rules say. I had this confusion, my DM had this confusion, Critical Role appears to have this confusion: it’s confusing. Probably because they had to add Hex Warrior on top of the already-existing Pact of the Blade, and so had to word things awkwardly.

So, let’s go through the different features *really* carefully.

> The influence of your patron also allows you to mystically channel your will through a particular weapon. Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch one weapon that you are proficient with and that lacks the two-handed property. When you attack with that weapon, you can use your Charisma modifier, instead of Strength or Dexterity, for the attack and damage rolls. This benefit lasts until you finish a long rest.

<sup>(*Xanathar’s Guide to Everything* description of the Hex Warrior feature)</sup>

This is the ability you get when you first choose the Hexblade patron and gain the Hex Warrior feature.<sup>1</sup> It allows you to pick some weapon that *already exists*, and use Charisma for attack and damage instead of Strength or Dexterity. This ability requires that the weapon you choose, that already exists, not have the two-handed property.

Now then, look at this:

> If you later gain the Pact of the Blade feature, this benefit extends to every **pact weapon** you conjure with that feature, no matter the weapon's type.

<sup>(*Xanathar’s Guide to Everything* description of the Hex Warrior feature, **emphasis** mine)</sup>

This is the next sentence after the previous quote; it’s part of the same 1st-level Hex Warrior feature. It specifies that the whole Charisma-to-attack-and-damage thing applies to “every pact weapon you conjure with that feature.”

What is a “pact weapon?” That phrase hasn’t been used before; this is the first time we’re seeing it. We have to look to Pact of the Blade:

> You can use your action to create a **pact weapon** in your empty hand. [...]
>
> You can transform one magic weapon into your **pact weapon** [...] You can then dismiss the weapon, shunting it into an extradimensional space, and it appears whenever you create your pact weapon thereafter.

<sup>(*Player’s Handbook* description of Pact of the Blade, **emphasis** mine)</sup>

So Pact of the Blade defines “pact weapon” for us, and specifies that you can get a pact weapon in one of two ways:

1. Conjuring it from thin air, or
2. Transforming a magic weapon into your pact weapon, which you can later conjure and dismiss at will.

So here’s the two big things that people misunderstand about Hex Warrior:

1. #### The chosen Hex Warrior weapon *is not* a pact weapon unless you transform it into one with Pact of the Blade

and

2. #### If you *don’t* do that, you can get *both* a chosen Hex Warrior weapon *and* a pact weapon

These are two separate abilities: one to touch a weapon and make it use Charisma, the other to conjure a weapon from thin air, so it counts as a pact weapon and gets several bonuses (including using Charisma). You can touch a weapon for Hex Warrior, and then *also* conjure a weapon with Pact of the Blade, and **both** get to use Charisma. Only the pact weapon from Pact of the Blade, however, benefits from various pact-weapon invocations, like *thirsting blade* that gives you an extra attack with a pact weapon. In order to benefit from that feature with the weapon chosen with Hex Warrior, you would have to transform it into your pact weapon, per the second option in Pact of the Blade—but if you did, you’d be able to just choose some other weapon you have lying around for Hex Warrior after your next long rest, since it being your pact weapon means it already benefits from Hex Warrior and there is no reason to choose it again.

The weapon you touch (which has no special name) must not be two-handed. A weapon you conjure, however, **can be** two-handed—and it still gets to use Charisma even though it’s two-handed, because Hex Warrior says “every pact weapon [...] no matter the weapon’s type.”

## Conclusion

Hex Warrior allows you to use Charisma for attack and damage with any one<sup>2</sup> non-two-handed melee weapon you touch. Hex Warrior *also* allows you to use Charisma with any pact weapon you create with Pact of the Blade—and Pact of the Blade is not restricted to non-two-handed weapons. So if you have both, you can conjure a two-handed weapon and use Hex Warrior on it.

1. <sub>Along with some proficiences that aren’t relevant here.</sub>
2. <sub>Per long rest.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

## Yes, any two-handed weapon can be your pact weapon

Pact of the Blade (PHB, pg. 107) says:

> You can use your action to create a pact weapon in your empty hand. You can choose the form that this **melee weapon** takes each time you create it. You are proficient with it while you wield it. [...]

There is no mention of any restriction on the weapon that you choose your pact weapon to be other than that it is a "melee weapon". Therefore, any melee weapon, regardless of whether it's two-handed or not, can be used as your pact weapon.

(And yes, this includes a lance, even though it doesn't have the two-handed property.)

## Regarding Hex Warrior

The Hex Warrior class feature (XGTE, pg. 55) includes this:

> If you later gain the Pact of the Blade feature, this benefit extends to every pact weapon you conjure with that feature, **no matter the weapon's type.**

If you have chosen a two-handed weapon as your pact weapon via Pact of the Blade, it appears as though Pact of the Blade's lack of restrictions overrides Hex Warrior's default restrictions of needing the weapon to lack the two-handed property, which is unusual for D&D 5e given that usually specific beats generic, but in this case, the feature is very specific about the fact that Pact of the Blade trumps this.

So although it's debatable whether an ordinary lance can become your "hex weapon", it seems as though your "pact weapon" can be a lance or a two-handed weapon and can benefit from the Hex Warrior feature (i.e. you can use CHA for attack rolls).