# Is a Hexblade Warlock's weapon their arcane focus by default?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, spellcasting-focus, hexblade

I'm playing a Hexblade with Pact of the Blade, and I was wondering whether the weapon you use as part of the Hex Warrior ability counts as an arcane focus, or only if it's a pact weapon and you have Improved Pact Weapons Invocation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## A Hex Weapon isn't an arcane focus automatically

The Hex Warrior class feature (XGtE, p. 55) says:

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch one weapon that you are proficient with and that lacks the two-handed property. When you attack with that weapon, you can use your Charisma modifier, instead of Strength or Dexterity, for the attack and damage rolls. This benefit lasts until you finish a long rest. If you later gain the Pact of the Blade feature, this benefit extends to every pact weapon you conjure with that feature, no matter the weapon's type.

Nowhere does it mention anything about the weapon being an arcane focus, so it isn't one.

As you've noted, the Improved Pact Weapon eldritch invocation (XGtE, p. 57) can allow you to use your weapon as an arcane focus, since it says:

> You can use any weapon you summon with your Pact of the Blade feature as a spellcasting focus for your warlock spells.

So you would need this eldritch invocation to use your hex weapon as an arcane focus. However, your hex weapon would also need to be your pact weapon, since it says "with your Pact of the Blade feature", so you would need to choose your hex weapon as the magic weapon you shunt out of existence and resummon with Pact of the Blade, as per the PHB (p. 107):

> You can transform one magic weapon into your pact weapon [...] You can then dismiss the weapon, shunting it into an extradimensional space, and it appears whenever you create your pact weapon thereafter.

If you were to choose your hex weapon as your pact weapon, then it would count as a pact weapon to satisfy the Improved Pact Weapon eldritch invocation. At that point, your hex weapon could be used as an arcane focus.

Comment: Even if it didn’t say “with your Pact of the Blade feature,” the weapon chosen for Hex Warrior **is not** a pact weapon (unless you choose to make it so by choosing it as the magic weapon you shunt out of existence and resummon with Pact of the Blade, in which case it meets both requirements). See [this answer for more details](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/131871/4563).

Comment: @KRyan I thought I'd covered that by my last sentence, but I have expanded it and made that more explicit. Thank you.

Comment: It might be noteworthy to mention that XGtE features a common magic item, *Ruby of the War Mage* (page 138), which can be attached to any weapon to turn it into a spellcasting focus. Of course, if you can get this item depends on your DM, but if you only want to use your weapon as a focus, it could be the way to go (e.g. if you already have a magic +1 weapon and won't benefit from IPW as much, since the +1 bonus is wasted)

Comment: @PixelMaster I hadn't forgotten about that nifty little item, but since this question was asking about whether the Hex Warrior feature makes a weapon an arcane focus by default, and not "What are all the ways my warlock can use their weapon as an arcane focus?", I eventually decided against including it.

Comment: @NathanS But it *is* a way for their warlock to use their weapon as an arcane focus. It’s not warlock-specific, but many warlocks might prefer to use it over burning an invocation on Improved Pact Weapon. Mine certainly would, if I got that ruby.

Comment: @KRyan Taking a 3 level dip in College of Swords Bard (XGtE, p. 15) is another way to allow the Hex Weapon to be used as an arcane focus (although more "expensive" than the ruby, I admit). But I decided that the scope of my answer should be limited to the context of the question, which is about the Hex Warrior class feature.

Comment: Well, that’s your choice—I admit that I had taken your quotation marks to indicate an actual quotation from the question, which I didn’t double-check, and now that I have I see the question is fairly narrowly-focused on Hex Warrior, unlike your quotation. (I would personally add such a value-add to this answer, but then that is strongly my preference and by no means everyone’s.)